# Update Multiple Row Values at Once using cell a reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, case-when

I've got a table I need to update, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing it.  Here's the schema

```
t1.id, t1.line, t1.item, t1.type

t2.id, t2.t1_id

t3.t2_id, t3.t1_line, t3.quantity1, t3.quantity2
```

t3 is basically maintaining a count of particular items from t1.

In this query, t3 will have n records.  The idea is that for each entry n in t3, there will be some quantity of items in t1 that should be associated to it.  I need to count those items and set t3.t1_quantity1 to that count.

[SQLFiddle Schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3bafe)

Using the above schema, in one query, I would want to know how many items of line 1 are type 0, and how many items of line 1 are type 1, and the results are entered into t3.quantity1 and t3.quantity2 respectively.  And the same for line 2, and so on if there were more lines in t3.

t3 at the end of the query would show the following

```
1, 1, 4, 2
1, 2, 4, 1
1, 3, 8, 3
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Please explain how table `t2` is involved.

Comment: t2 is the only directly related table to t1.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Lets just say I can't directly reference T1 from T3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE` and `JOIN` with `CASE WHEN` and `COUNT` to make it.

1. write a subquery to get `quantity1`, `quantity2` count by `line` colnum from `t1` table.
2. `join` `t2`, `t3` tables by `t1.line`
3. `UPDATE` data to `t3` table.

look like this.

```
 UPDATE result
 SET quantity1 = t.qty1,
     quantity2 = t.qty2
 FROM(
   select line,
    COUNT(case when type = 0 then 1 END) qty1,
    COUNT(case when type = 1 then 1 END) qty2
   from t1 
   GROUP BY line
 ) t 
 INNER JOIN t2 on t2.t1_id = t.line
 inner join t3 result on t.line = result.t1_line
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1af1/1)

**[Results]**:

```
| t2_id | t1_line | quantity1 | quantity2 |
|-------|---------|-----------|-----------|
|     1 |       1 |         4 |         2 |
|     1 |       2 |         4 |         1 |
|     1 |       3 |         8 |         3 |
```

Comment: This is interesting, I will play around with it and let you know how it works out.

Comment: I may have messed things up a bit trying to simplify the question.  This did work in fiddle, but I can't get it to work when I apply it to the actual query I'm working on.